# React-Native's navigator.geolocation is undefined

Tags: react-native, geolocation

`console.log(navigator.geolocation) //undefined`

`console.log(navigator)`:

```
WorkerNavigator {hardwareConcurrency: 8, appCodeName: "Mozilla", appName: "Netscape", appVersion: "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKi…L, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36", …}
appCodeName: "Mozilla"
appName: "Netscape"
appVersion: "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
connection: NetworkInformation {onchange: null, effectiveType: "4g", rtt: 100, downlink: 4.3, saveData: false}
deviceMemory: 8
hardwareConcurrency: 8
language: "en-US"
languages: (3) ["en-US", "en", "es"]
locks: LockManager {}
onLine: true
permissions: Permissions {}
platform: "MacIntel"
product: (...)
storage: StorageManager {}
usb: USB {onconnect: null, ondisconnect: null}
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
get product: ƒ getValue()
set product: ƒ setValue(newValue)
__proto__: WorkerNavigator
```

I am using React Native 0.59 on iOS.

In info.plist, I have both: `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` and `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description`

CocoaPods: http://dpaste.com/2W9Y57E
Info.plist: http://dpaste.com/1CTG8GP

Comment: Why does `navigator` turn into `WorkerNavigator`?

Comment: [does your iphone have geolocation enabled](https://www.badgermapping.com/knowledgebase/turn-geolocation-iphone/)?

Comment: Can you post your `Info.plist` and also if you're using cocoapods

Comment: Do you have `RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj` as a sub-project under libraries? Open xcode and check the section under libraries. Share the way you have created this project as by default it should work. if you are using cocoapod for react, then you need to add subspec `RCTGeolocation`

Comment: @manishg I did not have `RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj` in Libraries, but I just added it.  I also linked binary `libRCTGeolocation.a` to libraries.  However, when I console.log(navigator), I still get `WorkerNavigator` without the geolocation option.

Comment: @manishg what do you mean add to subspecs? What if I want to keep my Podfile as-is?

Comment: react-native uses [`navigator.geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation) as a browser polyfill. The issue may be with the mobile browser. You could try to test the `navigator` interface in your mobile safari browser [with the developer tools following this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807314/7295772)

Comment: @TIMEX I still believe the JS binding is not done correctly. I would dig more to see if the libraries are linked correctly. Maybe compare your project with the build log or project structure of a sample project created using “react native init”. I looked at your cocoa pod snippet and I see that you are not using react pod so you don’t need the subspec

Comment: @TIMEX I believe it is an issue with `navigator.geolocation` and I include the [`geolocation api interface` specifications](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#geolocation_interface). There is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630305) affecting `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36`. You can find [the open github issue in the `w3c/geolocation-api` repo](https://github.com/w3c/geolocation-api/issues/11).

Comment: @TIMEX [Geolocation API Removed from Unsecured Origins in Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only). Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the user's location using the HTML5 Geolocation API **from pages delivered by non-secure connections**. This means that **the page that's making the Geolocation API call must be served from a secure context such as HTTPS**.

Comment: another question is why the [interface](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#navigator_interface) `partial interface Navigator { readonly attribute Geolocation geolocation; };` is missing the geolocation. You can head to any website and deny authorization to be geolocated (I just did) and `navigator.geolocation` will be defined, the only difference is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` will not return the `position`.

Answer (score 5):

> The [**`WorkerNavigator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator) interface represents a subset of the Navigator interface allowed to be accessed from a [**`Worker`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker). Such an object is initialized for each worker and is available via the **`WorkerGlobalScope.navigator`** property obtained by calling **`window.self.navigator`**.
>
> The `Worker` interface of the [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) represents a background task that can be easily created and can send messages back to its creator. Creating a worker is as simple as calling the `Worker()` constructor and specifying a script to be run in the worker thread.

running `navigator` on any web page will return a [`Navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) instance

```
>> navigator
Navigator { permissions: Permissions, mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray, plugins: PluginArray, doNotTrack: "unspecified", maxTouchPoints: 0, mediaCapabilities: MediaCapabilities, oscpu: "Intel Mac OS X 10.13", vendor: "", vendorSub: "", productSub: "20100101" }
```

running navigator inside the `react-native` app will return a [`WorkerNavigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator) instance. The `WorkerNavigator` is a background task.

```
>> navigator
WorkerNavigator { geolocation: Object, hardwareConcurrency: 4, appCodeName: "Mozilla", appName: "Netscape"… }
```

The [`WorkerNavigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator) interface is not fully compatible/tested with all browsers, but I tested the functionality on the `Iphone X` emulator and `navigator.geolocation` is `defined`.

[image: Worker Navigator Compatability with Browsers]

Several posts on stackoverflow complain about `Chrome` or `Safari` returning `WorkerNavigator geolocation undefined` and as explained [in the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315863/7295772)

## Does `navigator.geolocation` belong to `navigator` in `Chrome`?

> **`navigator.geolocation`** belongs to `navigator` in the `main thread` only, but doesn't belong to `navigator` in the `worker thread`.
>
> two navigators have independent implementations on the `C++` side. That is why `navigator.geolocation` is not supported in the `worker` thread.

Chromium includes separates interfaces for the [**`Navigator`**](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/navigator.h?g=0) and the [**`WorkerNavigator`**](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/workers/worker_navigator.h?g=0) C++ implementation.

> `Navigator` is an attribute of `DOMWindow`, while `WorkerNavigator` is an attribute of `WorkerGlobalScope`.

Users on StackOverflow complain that [chrome webworker does not have the `geolocation` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549431/7295772)

> The navigator attribute of the WorkerGlobalScope interface must return an instance of the WorkerNavigator interface, which represents the identity and state of the user agent (the client):

```
[Exposed=Worker]
interface WorkerNavigator {};
WorkerNavigator includes NavigatorID;
WorkerNavigator includes NavigatorLanguage;
WorkerNavigator includes NavigatorOnLine;
WorkerNavigator includes NavigatorConcurrentHardware;
```

The `geolocation` method is not included in the [`WorkerNavigation`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#the-workernavigator-object) and [`WorkerLocation`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-locations) interfaces

> The `Navigator` is initialized for each worker and is available via the **`WorkerGlobalScope.navigator`** property obtained by calling `window.self.navigator`.

as described in the [**`WorkerNavigator`**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#the-workernavigator-object) api docs, it does not include the `geolocation()` method.

If you persist having this issue you may consider following this guide, manually creating your [`worker`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#examples-6) and testing the methods on different browsers.

## `navigator.permissions?` to detect geolocation support

> The [**`WorkerNavigator.permissions`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator/permissions) read-only property returns a [**`Permissions`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions) object that can be used to query and update permission status of APIs covered by the Permissions API.

```
self.permissions.query({name:'notifications'}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.state === 'granted') {
    showNotification();
  } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
    requestNotificationPermission()
  }
});
```

More information [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/3571)

## Steps to **Troubleshoot** the Issue

1. You are running `console.log` with the `react-native-debugger` tools and
       maybe the output is the one given from your mac browser and not your phone. Disable `debugging` on your emulator and show us the output of `console.warn(navigator)` and `console.warn(navigator.geolocation)`

   ```
   appVersion: "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103
   Safari/537.36"
   ```

As in the image below, `console.warn(navigator)` will return a `WorkerNavigator` Object in the `react-native-debugger-tools`, while it returns `{product:"ReactNative", "geolocation": {}}` in the emulator. React-native will not display the `console.log` inside the emulator.

[image]

2. Do you experiment this issue only on Iphone or also on Android?
3. are you wrongly importing  the `geolocation` object on top of your
   component?

   ```
   import { navigator } from ...
   ```
4. Do you know that the [native geolocation
   library](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)
   offers much more accurate api and a wider devices support?
5. Your issue seems to be connected to some browser not fully
   supporting the [**`WorkerNavigator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator) interface. Do you
   disagree on this last point and can you provide us some proof that
   we are wrong. `React-Native` is using the browser api to run
   `geolocation` in the background. You can recreate the same scenario
   in your [iphone emulator safari `developer console`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807314/7295772) following this instructions to create the [**`WorkerNavigator`** instance](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#examples-6) and then retrieving your location. You could demonstrate the `WorkerNavigator` works on your Emulator Safari/Chrome browsers.
6. Have you consider opening an issue at the
   [`w3c/geolocation-api`](https://github.com/w3c/geolocation-api/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) repository? Have you considered opening
   a [bug report in chromium](https://www.chromium.org/issue-tracking)?

Comment: So how do I fix it? I just want to use `navigator.geolocation`, but it's undefined.

Comment: @TIMEX I updated my post with the chapter **Steps to Troubleshoot the Issue**, I would like to see the output of `console.warn(navigator)` and `console.warn(navigator.geolocation)` with the `react-native-debugger` tools disabled. Please provide me any additional feedback to help you troubleshoot this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

None of the things the other guy said were able, clearly, to solve my problem.
At least for me that I'm using RN 0.60, I discovered that they extracted it (like many other packages) in an external package.
I thought about it of course, considering the decisions about the so called "lean core", but in rn docs nothing was written on the location extraction.

So here this is the package and here you find the new guide to configure it:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation

Don't know if it isn't available in 0.59 too